# unable to create table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Below is my HTML fine. I am getting a blank page as output

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var content = "<table>"
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
content += '<tr><td>' + 'answer' +  i + '</td></tr>';
}
content += "</table>"
$('#myTable').append(content);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myTable"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

the output that i expect is 
    
    answer 1
    answer 2
    .......
    answer 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code in [**document-ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler. it specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded. like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Your code
});
```

You should read [When should I use jQuery's document.ready function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062246/when-should-i-use-jquerys-document-ready-function)

Also you are using incorect id. use

```
$('#myTable').append(content);
```

instead of

```
$('#here_table').append(content);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPJGs/)

Answer (score 2):

Your js isn't waiting for the document to load, and missing 2 semi-colons.

Try changing your js to:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var content = "<table>";
  for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    content += '<tr><td>' + 'answer' +  i + '</td></tr>';
  }
  content += "</table>";
  $('#here_table').append(content);
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Table is incorrect use `$('#myTable').append(content);`

Comment: ahh well spotted, I missed that @Satpal :)

Answer (score 0):

ID change is the only thing you need to do:

```
$('#myTable').append(content);
```