# Global Variables 'undefined' in jQuery

Tags: jquery

In the following code

```
<script>
    var vars = {}
    $("document").ready(function() {
        vars.var1 = 2;
        alert(vars.var1);    //shows 2;
    });
    alert(vars.var1);        //shows undefined
</script>
```

Why is vars.var1 undefined?

Comment: Also don't forget the semicolon after your `var` declaration

Comment: @tomaroo Good idea, but that semicolon is optional. http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: `var x = {}; alert(x.y); x.y = 1;` is essentially what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly,

`$("document").ready` should be `$(document).ready` (no quotes)

Secondly,

The code `alert(vars.var1)` executes before the code inside the `$(document).ready()` function.

Because `vars` is only assigned a `var1` property inside the `$(document).ready()` function (which happens after the `alert` is executed), `vars.var1` will be `undefined` when you `alert(vars.var1)`;

Answer (score 4):

The code in `$(document).ready()` doesn't run until after the DOM is loaded. The `alert` is executed immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Because the function defined in `$("document").ready` is only executed when the document has been fully loaded. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062246/when-should-i-use-jquerys-document-ready-function) helps as well.

Answer (score 0):

you aren't setting a value until the document is read. when you call alert(vars.var1); and it returns undefined you are actually calling it before you set it since that code executes before the document is fully ready.