# Why Jquery is not working for asp.net textbox's CssClass Property?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am tying to validate the textboxes for achieving 'alphabets only' property in asp.net page with Jquery.

Here is the code

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     .............codes.............

      <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.alph').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z\s]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Alphabets only');
            return false;
        }
    });
   </script>
 .............codes.............

 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" CssClass="alph" BorderColor="Gray" Font-Size="Large" Height="25" Width="250" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

This code didn't work and I am sure my computer is connected to the internet to reach code.jquery.com. Help me please.

Comment: When you type $('.alph') to developer console, can you see the textbox showing up?

Comment: ok let me try.. one moment please

Comment: you meant the intelligence! when I try to add cssclass prop, it didn't pop up "alph" as one of the listed items -@vgSefa

Comment: Perhaps the Jquery class selector works only for class and not for CssClass

Comment: put an alert or console inside your function to first verify if your jQuery code is executing or not.

Comment: @user2314737 - No, `CssClass` ultimately renders as `class` in browser so jQuery selector picks that.

Comment: Make sure CssClass was really applied as class for txt_name element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this script code after `Document.ready` block

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.alph').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z\s]+$");

        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Alphabets only');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Before you can safely use jQuery you need to ensure that the page is in a state where it's ready to be manipulated. With jQuery, we accomplish this by putting our code in a function, and then passing that function to `$(document).ready()`. The function we pass can just be an anonymous function.

Comment: I figured it out too. Thanks

Comment: Most welcome ..you can find here more about Document ready http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062246/when-should-i-use-jquerys-document-ready-function

Answer (score 0):

My mistake! Since I am new to Jquery I didn't know about 'doc.ready' I corrected the code as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#<%=txt_name.ClientID %>').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z\s]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Alphabets only');
            return false;
        }
    });
    });
```

Code works perfect!