# Unable to change content inside div tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was creating this very basic program using JQuery but somehow it's not working. I spent 20 mins on it but couldn't figure it out. Don't know what I am missing in it.
The code is like this:

```
<head>
    <script>
        $('#error').html('<p>There are 4 horses.</p>');
                            or
        alert($('#error').html());
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="error">
            <h2>hello</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

can you guide me where I am wrong.

Comment: It works http://jsfiddle.net/omor6L0m/1/ .... are you including Jquery ? . Any console error?

Comment: what is the error you see in console ?

Comment: Please explain a bit clearer what you are trying to do as this can be interpreted differently. Are you trying to replace the word hello or are you trying to add the <p> tag after it? why do you have the random uncommented `or` statement in your JavaScript? did you mean to comment it?

Comment: @DanielPinzon there was no error. I wasn't using the document.ready(function()) and forgot to use the <script src="">.

and in JSFildle tool, don't you have to use both of these things..

Comment: @Arkantos: there was no error, I forgot to put the event and the script tag in it.

Comment: @KHeaney: or means that that the other option was also not working and yes I was trying to replace the hello with <p>

Comment: @MunishGupta I just suppose that you have included jquery ... on JSFiddle at the left side you can see "Frameworks & Extensions" where you can select Jquery and any version that selection includes the script source.

Comment: @DanielPinzon: yup. you are right and it's a great tool to use. 
Thanks for all you r help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `document.ready` which is an event which fires up when document is ready.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     $('#error').html('<p>There are 4 horses.</p>');
});
```

## What is document.ready?

document.ready is not needed for anything else than manipulating the DOM accurately. What I mean is that when you develop a large jQuery plugin for example you hardly use it throughout the code because you're trying to keep it dry, so you abstract as much as possible in methods that manipulate the DOM but are meant to be invoked later on. When all your code is tightly integrated the only method exposed in document.ready is usually init where all the DOM magic happens.

*Want to know more about document.ready? check this:[When should I use jQuery's document.ready function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062246/when-should-i-use-jquerys-document-ready-function)*

Answer (score 1):

Put the code

```
$('#error').html('<p>There are 4 horses.</p>');
```

inside of

```
$(document).ready( function() {

});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready( function() {
 $('#error').html('<p>There are 4 horses.</p>');
 alert($('#error').html());
});
//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="error">
         <h2>hello</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it worked..
I didn't put the other <script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>

Comment: i thought it will work without the jquery src, but i guess I was wrong.
Thanks a lot...

Comment: @MunishGupta Jquery is a library so everytime you want to use some of their functions and codes you need to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the [function on page load](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(function() {
$('#error').html('<p>There are 4 horses.</p>');
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nygvmhm5/)

Comment: You need to post more of your coding, if you want to get quality answers @MunishGupta

Comment: got it..
first i didn't put the document.ready(function()) and second i didn't used the script src code.
I didn't use them for a reason but i guess i was wrong, no matter i have to use them both.
and thanks for your help..