# JavaScript won't load when opening my webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to run this code but every time I open my webpage it doesn't load and I don't get the text I echo with PHP in the file "money.php". But if I open the console in my browser and run the code it does load. How can I fix this?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$('[data-update]').each(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var target = self.data('update');   
  var refreshId =  setInterval(function() { self.load(target); }, self.data('refresh-interval'));
});
</script>
```

```html
<div data-update="money.php" data-refresh-interval="500">
```

Comment: do you have loaded jquery file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use jQuery's document.ready function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062246/when-should-i-use-jquerys-document-ready-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use This

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('[data-update]').each(function () {
                var self = $(this);
                var target = self.data('update');
                var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
                    self.load(target);
                }, self.data('refresh-interval'));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

OR This

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('[data-update]').each(function () {
                var self = $(this);
                var target = self.data('update');
                var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
                    self.load(target);
                }, self.data('refresh-interval'));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you check the answer??

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in `$(function(){ ... });` so it runs after the DOM is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('[data-update]').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var target = self.data('update');   
    var refreshId =  setInterval(function() { self.load(target); }, self.data('refresh-interval'));
  });
});
</script>
```

More info:  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

Run the javascript/JQuery after

```
<div data-update="money.php" data-refresh-interval="500">
```