# Replace certain html with other html using .html isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html

```
<div id="items-content">
<p><img class="fr-dib" src="http://i.imgur.com/bEDR9dc.png" data-imgslap="{{image-key}}" style="width: 214px;"></p>
</div>
```

And i want to replace `src="http://i.imgur.com/bEDR9dc.png"` with `src="http://i.imgur.com/mJyABlG.jpg"`

I have the following jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#items-content').html( 'src="http://i.imgur.com/bEDR9dc.png"' ) {
    return 'src="http://i.imgur.com/mJyABlG.jpg"';

    }
} );
```

I'm learning JQuery still and I don't know where I have gone wrong. Would appreciate the help.

**Update**

I plan on using the same method of replacing the image to replace something like `data-imgslap=` with `src=`. Basically how do I replace html text 'x' with 'y' (They will only ever be html attributes text being replaced).

Comment: I haven't used much jQuery, but it looks like you're replacing the *complete contents* of your `<div>` with just `src=...`, leading to something like `<div>src=...</div>`. I'd recommend you use the debugging features of your browser so see the resulting HTML, that usually helps me to see what's happening. You probably want to use jQuery's `.attr()` function to alter the `src` value.

Answer (score 0):

### Update a DOM `img` tag's `src`

You're looking for jQuery's [`attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to update a single attribute's value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#items-content .fr-dib').attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/mJyABlG.jpg"');
} );
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/patrickberkeley/0wefe37t/

---

### Update a DOM `img` `src` with a value from a `data` attr

To update one attribute with another attribute's value (in this example updating an image's `src` with a data attribute's value):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $img = $('#items-content [data-imgslap]');
  var newSrc = $img.data('imgslap');
  
  $img.attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/' + newSrc + '.jpg"');
} );
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/patrickberkeley/bx686410/2/

---

### Regex to replace `img` `src` in a string

Based on the comments you've left though, it seems like your goal is to a value in a string (rather than updating an `img` element's src in the DOM).

In order to do that:

```
var str = '<div id="items-content"><p><img class="fr-dib" src="http://i.imgur.com/bEDR9dc.png" data-imgslap="mJyABlG" style="width: 214px;"></p></div>';
var newSrc = 'http://i.imgur.com/mJyABlG.png';
var newStr = str.replace(/<img(.*)src=[\"|\'](.*?)[\"|\'](.*)/, "<img$1src='" + newSrc + "'$3");
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/patrickberkeley/qrdt1esz/1/

Notice you *do not `$(document).ready()` because [you're not selecting something from the dom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13062316/916734). The above regex should handle: single and double quotes and any combination of attrs on either side of the `img`'s `src`.

Comment: This looks like it will replace all images to the one image. I just want that particular image to be changed so an attr with a certain value.

Comment: How would i change an attribute with a certain value to a different attr and value?

Answer (score 0):

Use attr() to solve this problem

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('#items-content .fr-dib').attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/mJyABlG.jpg"'); } );
```

Or use regular expression

```
your_string.replace(/(<img\s class\=\"fr-dib\"\ssrc=")(.*?)("\s?\/>)/, "$1http://i.imgur.com/mJyABlG.jpg $3");
```

Comment: How would i change an attribute with a certain value to a different attr and value? e.g. src `'src', 'http://i.imgur.com/mJyABlG.jpg'` to `'class', 'classname'` I think the string replace might be what im looking for, the html comes form the db so i might be able to change those strings as it comes from the db

Comment: Use reg exp to change the content