# Why does onclick = function() does not work inside document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Looking at [When should I use jQuery's document.ready function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062246/when-should-i-use-jquerys-document-ready-function) and [Form submit button onclick does not call my JS function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221978/form-submit-button-onclick-does-not-call-my-js-function?noredirect=1&lq=1) gives a sense that using `$document.ready(function(){})` should have no harm in the code, rather it is for the good.

But when I enter a function into the `onclick` method of button, the functions inside `ready()` statement don't get executed. Why so?

As an example, this code does not give an alert

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function f(){
  alert("alert");
  }
})
/*function f(){
  alert("alert");
  } */
```

```html
<button onclick="f()">
My Button
</button>
```

I understand that if I use the jQuery selectors to make it work, it will (`$("button").click(f)`). But why does this method fail?

Comment: onclick need method in global scope

Comment: do not define functions inside `.ready`

Comment: Because you are defining it in the outer function that is called on document load.

Comment: As others have said, the issue is due to scope. However it's important to note here that the inline `onX` attributes are no longer considered good practice and their user should be avoided. Always attach your event handlers unobtrusively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem of scope - functions declared inside functions is not accessible outside the outer functions just like variable declared inside functions:

```
(function(){
    var a = 'hello';
    function b () {
        console.log(a);
    }
})();

a;   // syntax error - a is undefined
b(); // syntax error - b is undefined
```

You can make it work by assigning the function to a global variable:

```
var f;

$(document).ready(function(){
  f = function(){
    alert("alert");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you declare a function you create a scope. Anything declared *inside* that scope is not accessible *outside* that scope.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // f is only accessible to other code declared in this function.
  function f(){
    alert("alert");
  }
})
```

The recommended way to do this with jQuery is to assign the on click handler function in the jQuery ready function.

HTML:

```
<button id="my-button-id">My Button</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // f is only accessible to other code declared in this function.
  function f(){
    alert("alert");
  }

  // Assign onclick here
  $('#my-button-id').on('click', f)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready() gets called after all of your html has finished loading. Since you are calling the "f()" function within your html, it calls "f()" before anything in "$(document).ready()" has run yet, meaning there is no definition for "f()".

It is common now to not even use "$(document).ready()" as long as you are loading that jQuery at the end of all of your html to avoid long load times. This will allow you to call "f()" from within your html and still have the rest of your jQuery load after your html.