# JS not firing at all

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I cannot get my button to trigger the javascript.  This seems to be quite straightforward? What is keeping the alert from showing up?

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript" 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">

  $(document).ready(function ()
  {
    $("#submitButton").click(function (e) {

            alert("Hello!!");
               
      });
   });
</script>


<input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" class="form-input" value="ButtonName" 
OnClick="ActionName" runat="server" />
```

Comment: A submit button submits the form, which causes the page to (at the least) reload. You would need `e.preventDefault()` in order for the `alert` to show.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Form submit button onclick does not call my JS function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221978/form-submit-button-onclick-does-not-call-my-js-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should end of the `script` tag if you add source only. And you should add extra script tag for internal script. And `input` type should be `button` because you are not submitting a form in here. If you will submit something, you should use a `form` element and listen it's `submit` event. You can use input `type="submit"` for it.

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
  {
    $("#submitButton").click(function (e) {

            alert("Hello!!");
               
      });
   });
```

```html
 <script type="text/JavaScript" 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" class="form-input" value="ButtonName" 
OnClick="ActionName" runat="server" />
```

Comment: But I do need to post the form back to the server.  It doesn't do that anymore.  The entire form is within a BeginForm and has an onlick value.  Can I still maintain both the front and back end?

Comment: You can still use submit type. I edited code.