# Basic code not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, methods

I am very new to jQuery, literally just trying to get it to work for the first time. Only the alert box works, but none of the other very simple methods I am trying out. Here are the files:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>jquery</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="myJavaScript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1 id="title">This is a title</h1>

    <p> This is some sample text.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function (){alert("this works!")});

$("#title").text("but this is not not working");
```

As you can see the example can't be simpler. I have off course downloaded the jquery-3.1.0.min.js file and put it in the same folder as the html. If I comment out the link, the alert stops working, so I now the file is being referenced OK. Why is the second line of jQuery not working? Many thanks, P

Comment: [When should I use jQuery's document.ready function?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13062512/3499595) Also there is a kind of a rule to place the custom scripts just before `</body>` that way the HTML is correctly parsed before the scripts are executed.

Comment: Any DOM operation belongs inside `$(document).ready(function(){`…`});`, not outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the DOM(the entire structure of your application) isn't loaded yet. You need to use a `$(document).ready`(makes sure the DOM is loaded before running jQuery code) or an event handler to make the change visible.

Comment: _“to make the change visible”_? That’s not exactly accurate. Without `$(document).ready` there isn’t even any change.

Comment: How is that not accurate?

Comment: 'Without $(document).ready there isn’t even any change.' -- And with $(document).ready there is so that's why i'm telling him to use $(document).ready , did you even read what i wrote though?

Comment: It still sounds confusing for someone who doesn’t know how to use `$(document).ready`.