# JQuery onclick code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Welcome,
I have this code:
html:

```
<script src="loginbox.js"></script>
<div class="menu" id="login">
      <p class="menu">LOG IN</p>
    </div>
```

js:

```
  $('#login').on('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('login').hide();
});
```

The div "login" isn't even clickable

Comment: did you put your Event Handler in a `$(document).ready()` function ?

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13062316/2008111 that might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#login').on('click', function(){
    $(document.getElementById('login')).hide();
  });
});
```

When you mix pure JS and jQuery, you need to wrap pure JS in a jQueryObject.

PS:
I'd swap the `$(document.getElementById('login'))` for a `$("#login")` if I were you

Comment: still doesn't work, + document is red in my text editor, I think it's something with this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Voltra/ugwkfffn/
Maybe you just did not include jQuery

Comment: Yes I didnt, now it works
Do you know how to add "button cursor"? when cursor is on div "login", it becomes "button cursor", you know, when cursor is on button

Comment: then just add :
`#login:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}`
In your css file