# Why do I need nested jQuery document.ready functions?

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I have some code:

```
$(function(){
    function foo() {
     var elem = $('.some-dom-elem');
     console.log(elem);
    }

    location.reload = function() {
     foo(); // returns undefined
    }
});
```

And here is the same code with the addition of an extra jQuery ready function:

```
$(function(){
    function foo() {
        var elem = $('.some-dom-elem');
        console.log(elem);
    }

    location.reload = function() {
        $(function(){
            foo(); // returns DOM element
        });

    }
});
```

Why do I need the extra jQuery ready function in the second code sample in order to make my foo function not return undefined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use jQuery's document.ready function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062246/when-should-i-use-jquerys-document-ready-function)

Comment: Your `foo` function doesn't return anything. Try adding `return elem` to it.

Comment: Who tells you you should? And why rewrite location.reload (assuming you can)

Comment: Assigning `location.reload` to a function is a very odd thing to be doing - assuming it's not already throwing an error

Comment: Simple answer.  You don't.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I opened my console on SO and tried to reassign the reload method.  Didn't log an error.  Hit F5, my logic did not happen and the page reloaded.  Doesn't seem like this is a valid thing to do.