# Lightbox is not working when click on image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone see why my lightbox is not working? I think I am staring blind on it?

There is a [JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0q2zkupa/).

```js
$(window).load(function() {

  $("section img").click(function() {
    $(".lightbox").fadeIn(300);
    $(".lightbox").append("<img src='" + $(this).attr("src") + "' alt='" + $(this).attr("alt") + "' />");
    $(".filter").css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).attr("src") + ")");
    /*$(".title").append("<h1>" + $(this).attr("alt") + "</h1>");*/
    $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
    if ($(this).is(":last-child")) {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "none");
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "block");
    } else if ($(this).is(":first-child")) {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "block");
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "none");
    } else {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "block");
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "block");
    }
  });

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(".lightbox").fadeOut(300);
    $("h1").remove();
    $(".lightbox img").remove();
    $("html").css("overflow", "auto");
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      $(".lightbox").fadeOut(300);
      $(".lightbox img").remove();
      $("html").css("overflow", "auto");
    }
  });

  $(".arrowr").click(function() {
    var imgSrc = $(".lightbox img").attr("src");
    var search = $("section").find("img[src$='" + imgSrc + "']");
    var newImage = search.next().attr("src");
    /*$(".lightbox img").attr("src", search.next());*/
    $(".lightbox img").attr("src", newImage);
    $(".filter").css("background-image", "url(" + newImage + ")");

    if (!search.next().is(":last-child")) {
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "none");
    }
  });

  $(".arrowl").click(function() {
    var imgSrc = $(".lightbox img").attr("src");
    var search = $("section").find("img[src$='" + imgSrc + "']");
    var newImage = search.prev().attr("src");
    /*$(".lightbox img").attr("src", search.next());*/
    $(".lightbox img").attr("src", newImage);
    $(".filter").css("background-image", "url(" + newImage + ")");

    if (!search.prev().is(":first-child")) {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "none");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  column-width: 300px;
  column-gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

section img {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  background: #7f8c8d;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(20px);
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.lightbox img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(0deg);
  max-height: 95vh;
  max-width: calc(95vw - 100px);
  transition: 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.4, 1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/*.lightbox:hover img{
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(180deg);
}*/

[class^="arrow"] {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

[class^="arrow"]:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.arrowr {
  right: 0;
}

.arrowr:after {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.arrowl {
  left: 0;
}

.arrowl:after {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:after,
.close:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e74c3c;
}

.close:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.close:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/600?image=634" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/300?image=455" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1500/700?image=629" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700?image=594" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/450?image=417" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/400?image=410" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/550?image=628" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/450?image=421" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/567?image=572" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/978?image=623" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/654?image=621" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/500?image=423" />
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1000/654?image=930" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/950?image=1045" />
</section>
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="arrowr"></div>
  <div class="arrowl"></div>
  <div class="close"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add jquery to your snippet

Comment: You have too much going on for so little. Try creating classes for each and use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` which will make the code easier to maintain and edit.

Comment: The problem is `$(window).load` is wrong. Does this answer your question? [When should I use jQuery's document.ready function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062246/when-should-i-use-jquerys-document-ready-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready` that causing the issue.. `$(document).ready` is fires up when document is ready.

See the Snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("section img").click(function() {
    $(".lightbox").fadeIn(300);
    $(".lightbox").append("<img src='" + $(this).attr("src") + "' alt='" + $(this).attr("alt") + "' />");
    $(".filter").css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).attr("src") + ")");
    /*$(".title").append("<h1>" + $(this).attr("alt") + "</h1>");*/
    $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
    if ($(this).is(":last-child")) {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "none");
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "block");
    } else if ($(this).is(":first-child")) {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "block");
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "none");
    } else {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "block");
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "block");
    }
  });

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(".lightbox").fadeOut(300);
    $("h1").remove();
    $(".lightbox img").remove();
    $("html").css("overflow", "auto");
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      $(".lightbox").fadeOut(300);
      $(".lightbox img").remove();
      $("html").css("overflow", "auto");
    }
  });

  $(".arrowr").click(function() {
    var imgSrc = $(".lightbox img").attr("src");
    var search = $("section").find("img[src$='" + imgSrc + "']");
    var newImage = search.next().attr("src");
    /*$(".lightbox img").attr("src", search.next());*/
    $(".lightbox img").attr("src", newImage);
    $(".filter").css("background-image", "url(" + newImage + ")");

    if (!search.next().is(":last-child")) {
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "none");
    }
  });

  $(".arrowl").click(function() {
    var imgSrc = $(".lightbox img").attr("src");
    var search = $("section").find("img[src$='" + imgSrc + "']");
    var newImage = search.prev().attr("src");
    /*$(".lightbox img").attr("src", search.next());*/
    $(".lightbox img").attr("src", newImage);
    $(".filter").css("background-image", "url(" + newImage + ")");

    if (!search.prev().is(":first-child")) {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "none");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  column-width: 300px;
  column-gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

section img {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  background: #7f8c8d;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(20px);
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.lightbox img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(0deg);
  max-height: 95vh;
  max-width: calc(95vw - 100px);
  transition: 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.4, 1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/*.lightbox:hover img{
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(180deg);
}*/

[class^="arrow"] {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

[class^="arrow"]:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.arrowr {
  right: 0;
}

.arrowr:after {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.arrowl {
  left: 0;
}

.arrowl:after {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:after,
.close:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e74c3c;
}

.close:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.close:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/600?image=634" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/300?image=455" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1500/700?image=629" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700?image=594" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/450?image=417" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/400?image=410" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/550?image=628" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/450?image=421" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/567?image=572" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/978?image=623" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/654?image=621" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/500?image=423" />
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1000/654?image=930" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/950?image=1045" />
</section>
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="arrowr"></div>
  <div class="arrowl"></div>
  <div class="close"></div>
</div>
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/3pvke4Lw/1/) also