# Jquery doesnt find input textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following code to populate KendoGrid, I used Jquery to get text-box value. text-box display the right value but Jquery is not returning what's in the textbox instead it return nothing.

```
<input asp-for="InvoiceID" name="InvoiceID" id="iid" />
<script>
    function additionalInfo() {
        return {
            invoiceID: $("#iid").val()
        }
    }    
</script>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<....WebUI.ViewModels.Project.BillingDocuments>()
    .Name("BillingDocuments")
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Hidden().Width(50);
            columns.Bound(p => p.PrintSequence).Title("Seg").Width(50);
            columns.Bound(p => p.DocumentType).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(m => m.Actions).ClientTemplate("<a class='text-primary' href='#= DocumentLocation #'>View</a>").Width(50);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:250px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(5)
        .Read(read => read.Action("BillingDocumentsRead", "Billing", new { Area = "Project"}).Data("additionalInfo")

        .Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
     )
)
```

I tried by setting the invoice ID value as

```
<script>
    function additionalInfo() {
        return {
            invoiceID:55
        }
    }    
</script>
```

and this works fine but jquery doesnt pick textbox value of `<input asp-for="InvoiceID" name="InvoiceID" id="iid" />`.

Comment: Look into `document.ready()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use jQuery's document.ready function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062246/when-should-i-use-jquerys-document-ready-function)

Comment: Are you expecting the user to input in that text box before making request?

Comment: @charlietfl I have value in this textbox  `<input asp-for="InvoiceID" name="InvoiceID" id="iid" />`  but jquery return empty value

Comment: I don't work with asp... does that generate `<input value="12378" name="InvoiceID" id="iid" />`.?  In other words populate the `value` attribute?

Comment: yes that works perfect with `value="12378"` or populate the value that i wanted to see with `<input value="12378" name="InvoiceID" id="iid" />`

Comment: First make sure you are using jquery, if you are then use value. Working example:
<input value="2" asp-for="InvoiceID" name="InvoiceID" id="iid" />

function additionalInfo() {
   return 'invoiceID: ' + $("#iid").val();  
 }    

additionalInfo();

Comment: try inspecting the input label see what id the browser renders and use that the select in jquery

Comment: @PrinjuKoshyVaidyan here is how it look when i inspect it `<input id="iid" type="number" data-val="true" data-val-required="The InvoiceID field is required." name="InvoiceID" value="" data-bind="value:InvoiceID">` but there is a value in the textbox

Comment: you are not calling the function anywhere? additionalInfo() to invoke that function

Comment: function additionalInfo() { var test=$('#iid').val();
        return {
            invoiceID:test
        }
    }     OR Try this?

Comment: @PrinjuKoshyVaidyan when i set invoiceID:55 or test it works fine, even if `<input  name="InvoiceID" value="55" id="iid" />` it works the problem is i have to use `<input asp-for="InvoiceID" name="InvoiceID" id="iid" />` and jquery doesnt get what's in the textbox.