# Where to define the javascript functions html/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problems calling functions "onclick".

Is it appropriate to use this methodology?
It tells me (function name) that it is not defined. While on other pages it works for me. I am learning.
I have read that it is "bad" to use "onclick" and that it is better to use:
`$(document).on('click', '#id', function (){`

If I use "$(document).on('click..." never problem.
However, it suits me to "call" the function since this way I can pass parameters.
Is there a way for "onclick" to work fine? In almost all popular browsers? What does it depend on if it works well? What matters because it fails?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by *"bad" to use "onclick"*, can you give an example of what you're thinking by that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062246/when-should-i-use-jquerys-document-ready-function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using onclick, it allows for variables.

For example, this works

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body onclick="alert('bruh')">x</body>
</html>
```

However, I think the current standard is to use event listeners. So in that case, it would be

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click',()=>{alert("bruh")})
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>x</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but calling functions (I don't know if the term "call" is correct).
The truth, I was 1 hour trying to see why it marked me (function name) as "undefined".
I couldn't see what the error was, but now it works for me. Between copy and copy desasher and undo, I lost and couldn't see the fault.

Comment: Between copy and paste everything, in the head, below, I use jquery, I don't know what I did, but now it works for me, as I said, between ctrl + z and ctrl + y and, in one way or another it worked. I have seen if, in the forum, that the exact same thing happened to others, marks the function as "undefined"