# Jquery submit form not responding

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

For some reason, my form has a submit button and the form has an id tag to it. When i do a test to call the .submit function, the form just closes.  Here is the example: http://overtheoceanfilms.com/admin/index.php (press the button in the "action" column)

The link to open the modal (i load the form from another page that gets loaded in the href tag.)

```
 <a href="inc/editInquiry.inc.php?id=<?php echo $row['customer_id'];?>" data-reveal-id="modal_inquiry_editUser"  data-reveal-ajax="true" id="<?php echo $row['customer_id'];?>"> <i class="fi-page-edit large"></i> </a>
```

Here is my modal:

```
<!--INQUIRY EDIT USER -->
<div id="modal_inquiry_editUser" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">


<a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery, very simple:

```
 $('#inquiry_editUserForm').submit(function() {

    alert('test');
});
```

PHP Form (editInquiry.inc.php)

```
<form id="inquiry_editUserForm" method="post" action="">
....stuff inside form
<button type="submit"> Update </button> 
</form>
```

Comment: So, you want to submit your form but the dialog must remain open?

Comment: yes - i updated the code above now to show more

Comment: all i'm trying to do is make sure it calls the function and alerts "test". It doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "click" event, instead of "submit". Also if you don't want to submit at the moment you click, you must suppress the default behaviour with "preventDefault", like this

```
$('#inquiry_editUserForm').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('test');
});
```

Just a reminder that `click` event is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )`

Comment: If you attach a `click` event to the entire form, it will get triggered every time it get a click

Comment: updated the code to show more. all i'm trying to do is make sure it calls the function and alerts "test". It doesn't

Comment: I accessed the exemple url and opened the form, if I bind the event manually, using browser console it works, give it a try. Maybe the problem is related to the moment you are binding the event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit your form but the dialog must remain open, then you should submit your form using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You can attach an event to the form it self, or to the submit button.

If you are going to use the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event, make sure to call `preventDefault()` or returning `false` at the end in order to cancel the submit action.

```
$('#inquiry_editUserForm').submit(function(evt) {
    //your code goes here
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: $(this).serialize() //Encode form elements as a string for submission.
        //If using serialize(), name attribute in form elements is required
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
    return false; //return false will cancel the page to reload/redirect
    //evt.preventDefault(); //or we can use preventDefault()
});
```

Almost the same applies to the `click` event in the submit button

---

I took a look to your page source, you are attaching your event to soon and the element with id `inquiry_editUserForm` does not exist yet. So, i recommend you that you find the right place to attach the event, and i think it is after the form is fully loaded.

Comment: thanks! i'm aware of this - the problem i'm having is when i press the submit button it doesn't even recognize the .submit function at all. but if i use a button with an onclick event, it will fire the function.

Comment: if you go to the page now, there is a 'customers' link, i made another modal with a form inside it already, and when you press the submit button, it does recognize the .submit function and alerts 'test'.

Comment: You are right! I see that it doesn't populate the form. Even though it's showing it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to return true to continue operation.

This is already answered here : [How to do something before on submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053394/how-to-do-something-before-on-submit)

Comment: Still no luck. My issue is something else just can't pin point it.

Comment: I gave you right answer on question asked above... We should see more code to debug it actaully, @MikeCerveni

Comment: all i'm trying to do is make sure it calls the function and alerts "test". It doesn't