# Form submit with hidden fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, hidden-field

I've got a form with 2 Hidden Fields and i want , when i hit the submit button to fill the fields with my script before sending it . My form looks like this :

```
<form method = "post" action = "Submit.php">
<input type="text" value="" >
...
<input type"hidden" value="" >
<input type"hidden" value="" >

<input type="submit" value="Sendme">

<script > //do something before send form </script>
```

The problem is that  ive got a field at the end of my form and i need the value of it  to fill the hidden fields with some calculation based on his value  before the form is submitted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do something before on submit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053394/how-to-do-something-before-on-submit)

Comment: Exactly what's your question?

Comment: I edited my question at the end so you can understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your question, I assumed that you want to set the values for hidden fields based on the calculation done on the entered value for a first text-box.

You can use the change method of the text-box to set the values of hidden fields, once you submit that will give you values of all the fields.

```
<input type="text" value="" id="inputBox">

<input type="hidden" value="" id="hidden1">
<input type="hidden" value="" id="hidden2">

$('#inputBox').change(function(){
   var value = $(this).val() + 10;
   $('#hidden1').val(value);
};
```

Comment: You're a king. Thanks a lot :).

Comment: @Random_Display_Name : , No problem, Glad to hear that :)